# Remove all occurrences of item(s) in list if it appears more than once

Tags: python

I need help with a coding challenge that is asking to remove all occurrences of an item within a list that appear more than once.  My code only removes one occurrence.  It will not remove the item completely.

```
def solution(data, n):
    for x in data:
        while data.count(x) > 1:
            data.remove(x)
            continue        
    print(data)

solution([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5], 1)
```

```
expected result: [1, 4]
actual restult: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: And what's the actual result?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I updated the question with the actual result. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you expect `[1, 4]`? Your logic says to remove the duplicates, not the original value too. Also: what's the point of `n`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is where I'm currently stuck.

Comment: Also, don't modify a list and remove elements while you're iterating over it

Comment: Are the duplicates always next to each other in the list?

Comment: The duplicates are not always next to each. Plus, the solution could be any list of numbers, with the length being no more than 100 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
def solution(data, n):
    for x in set(data):
        if data.count(x) > n:
            while x in data:
                data.remove(x)
    return data
```

Some explanation:

- `set(data)` makes that every value is checked only once, even if it occurs multiple times in `data`;
- you should remove the `continue` statement, it does not do what you probably want it to do;
- look carefully what I am doing with the `if` statement and the `while` statement;
- in your code, the `n` argument was not used, I assumed that it should replace the `1` in the `if`-line.

Update: Here is the one line version!

```
solution = lambda data, n: [x for x in set(data) if data.count(x) <= n]
```

You can call the solution function the same as before. 
If you are puzzled about this syntax, you could search 'python list comprehensions' and 'python lambda'.

Answer (score 8):

you can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count all instances of each element in `data`, then print only the relevant ones based on this count:

```py
from collections import Counter


def solution(data, n):
    histogram = Counter(data)
    print([d for d in data if histogram[d] <= n])

solution([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5], 1)
```

or just use `data.count()` directly:

```py
def solution(data, n):
    print([d for d in data if data.count(d) <= n])

solution([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5], 1)
```

Comment: If it's a coding challenge, it would probably be a good idea to only use a `set` or a `dict`. But you're right, `Counter` is the right tool otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a coding challenge, it might be better to not rely upon Python-specific stuff, like `collections` or the `count()` function.

You could generically do this in any language using a hash table, which in Python is just a dictionary.

I assume the presence of the parameter `n` is to make the threshold above which you remove the number configurable, and not simply hard-coded to 1.

```py
data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]

def solution(data, n):
    occurrences = {}
    # count occurrences
    for item in data:
        occurrences[item] = occurrences.get(item, 0) + 1
    # return trimmed data
    trimmed_data = []
    for item in data:
        if occurrences[item] <= n:
            trimmed_data.append(item)
    return trimmed_data

solution(data, 1)
```

yields
`[1, 4]`

This has O(n) time complexity.

You can save the second list by re-using the first one:

```py
def solution(data, n):
    occurrences = {}
    # count occurrences
    for item in data:
        occurrences[item] = occurrences.get(item, 0) + 1
    # return trimmed data
    data.clear()
    for k, v in occurrences.items():
        if v <= n:
            data.append(k)
    return data
```

Comment: Technically, that's not reusing the list, it is reusing the name binding, but assigning it a brand new list.